# calling SQL by webservice, but it doesn't work

Tags: java, web-services, postgresql

I got a problem with my codes.

I wrote a simple java application connected to postgreSQL, code at below, it's work.

```
package jdbctest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JDBCtest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "1234";
        String SQL="";

        try 
        {
            String a="pswd";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            //Insert            
            SQL = "Insert into inserttable(idnb,data)  Values('ID',?)";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pst.setString(1,a);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(JDBCtest .class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {

                if(con != null) con.close();
                if(pst!=null) pst.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(JDBCtest .class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

then I created a webservice to do same thing, WSDL created without error.

```
package Use.SQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "pgSQL")
public class pgSQL 
{
    @WebMethod(operationName = "insert")
    @Oneway
    public void insert(@WebParam(name = "infor") String infor) 
    {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet Check = null;

        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "1234";
        String SQL="";
        try 
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            //Insert            
            SQL = "Insert into inserttable(idnb,data)  Values('ID',?)";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            pst.setString(1,infor);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(pgSQL .class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (con != null) con.close();
                if(pst!=null) pst.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(pgSQL .class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }    
    }
 }
```

after all, I wrote an application calling wsdl like below.

```
public class JavaApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        insert("pswd");
    }    

    private static void insert(java.lang.String infor) {
        use.sql.PgSQL_Service service = new use.sql.PgSQL_Service();
        use.sql.PgSQL port = service.getPgSQLPort();
        port.insert(infor);
    }
}
```

Running project done without error, but nothing happend in database.

guys, have any idea about the problem?

---

Thanks guys, you really gave me useful messages.

now I realized the problem cause by the driver.

I surely added the jar file in project, but don't know how, webservice can't get it.

still not solve yet.

---

It finally works after import Driver by code.

thanks guys :D

Comment: Where are you running your webservices? Have you imported all the required jars into your application lib?

Comment: the application, webservice and database run in same PC.   the only jar file I used is postgreSQL driver, and yes, I add this jar file in.

Comment: No errors? Is the webservices getting invoked?  Can you put more loggers or use debug pointers if you are using an IDE?

Comment: oh I see.
I tried Tomcat server at first, It shows nothing about webservice, so I just put it in my application hope it runs well but its not.

I try GlassFish server this time, compiles all good, but when I test webservice, it goes SQLException all the time.

Comment: Thats better. Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: stack trace, u mean SQLException ex?

Comment: Yea.. the one which gives a lot of information about the exception that occurs, with a lot of packages and line numbers etc

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql//localhost/postgres

Comment: Okay, now add the POSTGreSQL driver (Jar file) into your lib folder inside your application folder and redeploy to Glassfish and try.

Comment: I'm sure it added at first but I try add it in application folder, but still get exceptions.  :'(

Comment: Okay, so now I need the screenshot of your deployed folder. Mainly to see what is inside the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: could it be the problem that there is nothing in forlder? here I upload some screeenshots.
http://postimg.org/image/9qniblceh/ , http://postimg.org/image/e0wok5ssf/ , http://postimg.org/image/pdq84xoun/ ,

Comment: Well there is nothing in the folder. You need to have the postgres jar file either in the WEB-iNF/lib or the server third party lib folder. Missing the jar file is what your application is cribbing about.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just get wrong foler, I found driver in /build/web/WEB-INF/lib/  not in  /web/WEB-INF. so there is jar in already. It makes me confuse now  http://postimg.org/image/u7pdaxxhd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres";
```

if your PostgreSQL port is not 80,please write port

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:port/postgres";
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your answer.
It remind me the things about port, but it dosen't work yet.
In phpPgAdmin, it shows port of postgreSQL server is 5432. 
so I tried localhost:5432 in program, and the error "No suitable driver found." 

Another wired question is
I didn't set port in first application code, but it works.

Comment: try move the driver jar to  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/

Comment: if you run it in tomcat,please try move the driver jar in tomcat/lib/

Comment: Hi again, I tried both of it. Still not working, I think the problem is about file path or project file path setting. So I tried import org.postgresql.Driver. but its still give me exceptions.

Comment: Can you post up the exceptions？

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance(); put it  in your code begin

Comment: Finally it works, thanks bro. But I still don't get it, why or how it happen?  Do you know that?

Comment: Because it needs to be registered in JVM。 DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver()) also ok.

Comment: OK, I'll get more information about it. much appreciate for your helps.